# Documentation - Describing the Flow

Tags: documentation, build-process, uml

I have various documents some are large some are small, we have to draw up some form of model that would describe how a user interacts with each document when following them for a build. For example, a user might.

Follow Document 1 to Section 10 then be pointed to Document 2 to complete then return back to Section 10 in document 1 etc.

Has anyone ever drawn up some sort of chart to demonstrate this kind of thing for documentation, it is fairly standard for systems but i have never done it regarding documentation and I am just wondering if there is a formal method of doing this for documentation and is there any examples or standard guides to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would use an [Activity diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) with [Swimlanes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swim_lane) for each document.

An alternative would be an [IDEF0 diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF0)(may be appropriate if there are instructions for completing each document, and/or different roles for different steps)

Comment: Thanks for that, Swimlanes that was the one I was looking for!